# JPA / Hibernate query for array overlap in Postgres using index

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `_varchar` column in my table that has been indexed with GIN to allow for efficient indexed searching of the array.

If I execute an SQL query like

```sql
select * from mytable where myarray && '{A}'
```

I can see the query planner will use my index and the query is fast.

Hibernate / JPA doesn't support use of this syntax, so to work around this, we have defined a function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_array_overlaps(left_array character varying[], right_array character varying[])
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
BEGIN
    return left_array && right_array;
END;
$function$
;
```

However, when this function is called, the query planner will no longer use the index and instead perform a full table scan.

Is there a workaround that will allow this predicate to be used within JPA / Hibernate and still allow usage of the index?

This predicate is part of a much larger `CriteriaQuery` so its not possible to just use a native query to achieve this.

Thanks!